# Dynamic vector of void* in C

Tags: c, vectors

I have implemented a simple dynamic vector library in C. It is a header-only library.

Full library listing -
`void_vector.h:`

```
#ifndef VOID_VECTOR_H
#define VOID_VECTOR_H

typedef enum {
    VV_SUCCESS,
    VV_MALLOC_FAILURE
} vv_err;

typedef struct vv {
    size_t length;
    size_t size;
    void *data[];
} void_vector;

void_vector* new_void_vector(size_t size);
vv_err vv_push(void_vector **vv, void *el);
void *vv_pop(void_vector *vv);
const void* vv_read_index(void_vector *vv, size_t index);
void delete_void_vector(void_vector *vv, void (del_el)(void*));

#ifdef VOID_VECTOR_IMPL
#undef VOID_VECTOR_IMPL

#include <stdlib.h>

#define defualt_size 16ul

void_vector*
new_void_vector(size_t size)
{
    if (!size) size = defualt_size;
    void_vector* vv = malloc(sizeof(void_vector) + sizeof(void*) * size);
    if (vv) {
        vv->size = size;
        vv->length = 0;
    }
    return vv;
}

vv_err
vv_push(void_vector **vv, void *el)
{
    if ((*vv)->length >= (*vv)->size) {
        void_vector *new_vv = realloc((*vv), sizeof(void_vector)
                                            + sizeof(void*) * (*vv)->size * 2);
        if (!new_vv) return VV_MALLOC_FAILURE;
        (*vv) = new_vv;
        (*vv)->size *= 2;
    }
    (*vv)->data[(*vv)->length] = el;
    (*vv)->length++;
    return VV_SUCCESS;
}

void*
vv_pop(void_vector *vv)
{
    if(vv->length == 0) return NULL;
    vv->length--;
    return vv->data[vv->length];
}

const void*
vv_read_index(void_vector *vv, size_t index)
{
    if (index > vv->length) return NULL;
    return (vv->data[index]);
}

void
delete_void_vector(void_vector *vv, void (del_el)(void*))
{
    if (!del_el) del_el = &free;
    for (int i = vv->length; i; i--) {
        del_el(vv->data[i-1]);
    }
    free(vv);
}

#endif /* VOID_VECTOR_IMPL */
#endif /* VOID_VECTOR_H */
```

I am using this as test bench - `void_vector_tb.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VOID_VECTOR_IMPL
#include "void_vector.h"

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    void_vector* vv = new_void_vector(4);

    char *strings[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        strings[i] = malloc(32);
        snprintf(strings[i], 32, "This is String: %d", i); 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vv_push(&vv, strings[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vv->length; i++) {
        printf("%d:\t%s\n", i+1, vv_read_index(vv, i));
    }

    char *s;
    while(s = (char*) vv_pop(vv)) {
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vv_push(&vv, strings[i]);
    }

    delete_void_vector(vv, NULL);
}
```

I am not using a make file. Compilation is performed by `gcc -ggdb void_vector_tb.c -o void_vector_tb`

I would greatly appreciate your time and any comments but I'm particularly interested in the following points:

- Am I doing anything dangerous in this?
- Is the code clear, what can I do to make it easier to follow?
- Is there an obvious way to greatly improve the efficiency?
- General style comments
- I'm not overly concerned about the contents of `void_vector_tb.c`.

I ran this through valgrind and got the following output:

```
==7009== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7009==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7009==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 14 frees, 1,616 bytes allocated
==7009== 
==7009== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7009== 
==7009== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7009== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I am trying to minimize use of external libraries (although I don't think it would be possible to avoid stdlib.h).

Comment: "Am I doing anything dangerous in this?" Yeah you are using void pointers :) They tend to kill type safety and there are many better ways of generic programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall, fairly good.

> Am I doing anything dangerous in this?

**Lack of comments**

I'd expect at least some commentary about the roll of the functions and how to use them near the function declaration section.

Assume a user will read the header and not delve into implementation.

**Unexpected type change**

The stored ellement is a `void *`, changing the return type to `const` is not good.

```
// const void* vv_read_index(void_vector *vv, size_t index)
void* vv_read_index(void_vector *vv, size_t index)
```

**Overuse of `NULL`**

`vv_pop(), vv_read_index()` return `NULL` as an error indicator and can return `NULL` as a valid return.  If `NULL` is not to be allowed (which I think is a bad idea) as a storable `void *`, `vv_push(&vv, NULL)` should error.

I'd re-work calls to return an error code on `vv_pop()`, like `vv_err vv_pop(void_vector **vv, void **el)`.

It seems odd to have 2 forms of error signaling: error codes and `NULL`.

**"default size"**

I see no real value in a default size of 16.  Suggest setting aside `size == 0` as something special and allow an initial vector size of 0.  Add code to handle doubling array size when size is 0.

Create a `VV_DEFAULT_SIZE 16u` if desired for the user to call with `new_void_vector(VV_DEFAULT_SIZE)`.

**Overflow**

I'd detect overflow in size computations.

**Tolerate freeing `NULL`**

`free(NULL)` is well defined.  I'd expect the same with `delete_void_vector(NULL, foo)`.  Currently code dies on this.

> Is the code clear, what can I do to make it easier to follow?

**Naming convention**

Recommend to use the same one prefix with all external types, names and functions.

```
// void_vector.h
vv.h

// VOID_VECTOR_H
VV_H

// void_vector* new_void_vector(size_t size);
void_vector* vv_new(size_t size);
```

Or use `void_vector` instead of `vv` throughout, not both.

**Allocate to the size of the object, not type**

Allocating to the size of the referenced object is 1) less error prone, 2) easier to review 3) easier to maintain than allocating to the type.

```
// void_vector* vv = malloc(sizeof(void_vector) + sizeof(void*) * size);
void_vector* vv = malloc(sizeof *vv + sizeof *vv->data * size);
```

**Avoid unnecessary suffixes**

An `L`, `l`, `LL`, `ll` is needed a lot less than one thinks.  In the following case, `L` certainty not needed.  The `u` *is* useful though.  I am curios as to why OP thought is was needed - what issue was of concern?

```
/// #define defualt_size 16ul
#define defualt_size 16u
```

**Use `const`**

`const` would help convey that the function is not altering `*vv`

```
// vv_read_index(void_vector *vv ...
vv_read_index(const void_vector *vv ...
```

> Is there an obvious way to greatly improve the efficiency?

Allocations only increase as `vv_pop()` does not reduce things. This can make for an inefficiency of memory usage.

IMO, a more advanced  scheme could decrease by 1/2 when size needed falls below 25% or 33%.

> General style comments

**Spell check**

```
// #define defualt_size 16ul
#define default_size 16ul
```

**`!` vs. `>`**

Minor: With arithmetic concerns, `>` is more readily understood that `!` negation.

```
// if (!size)
if (size > 0)
```

> I'm not overly concerned about the contents of void_vector_tb.c.

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

Replace `10` with `#define VV_STR_N 10`,  `32` with `#define VV_STR_SZ 3`2,

**Cast not needed**

```
// while(s = (char*) vv_pop(vv)) {
while(s = vv_pop(vv)) {
```

Comment: First off thank you for the detailed and extended review. I will make your recommended changes this evening. I have a single follow up question. Currently the function `const void* vv_read_index(vv, i)` returns a `const void*` and you are recommending it should return `void*`.Originally I did this as I considered the returned value to "belong" to the the vector and did not want the user changing it. Is there a better way to achieve this without confusing types or do I just trust the user not to corrupt the data store?

Comment: @eternalnewbie `vv` stores a _pointer_.  Returning `const void *` or `void *` does not allow the use to change the _pointer_ stored in `vv`. Returning `const void *` does not allow the use to change what the pointer points to.  That is not `vv` concern so `vv_read_index()` should return what it was given, a `void *`.  It sounds like to are thinking about returning the address of the pointer: `const void**
vv_index_address(void_vector *vv, size_t index)
{
    if (index > vv->length) return NULL;
    return (&vv->data[index]);
}`

Comment: I was trying to avoid a situation where the user would  call `p = vv_read_index(vv, i);` then `free(p);` finally followed by `delete_vv(vv);`. This would cause double a free() which would be UB. I tried this out and it works and it works fine.

Comment: I think my best option is to take your advice and return void*. But also note  in the usage comments and readme about the potential UB.

Comment: I now see _why_ you coded a return of `const`.  Yet the memory management of the `void*` pointers is not really the concern of `vv`.

Comment: @eternal newbie Another oops.  `for (int i = vv->length; i; i--) {` --> `for (size_t i = vv->length; i; i--) {`.  This implies you (and I)  did not compile with all warnings on.  Save time enable all warnings.

Answer (score 4):

I have two things to add to @chux's comments.

The `vv_read_index` function can read past the end of the vector if `index` is equal to `vv->length`.  If `vv->length == vv->size`, this will read past the end of allocated memory.

While the cast in `while(s = (void *) vv_pop(vv))` is not needed, the use of an assignment within a conditional test can be misread as a typo.  (Some compilers will issue a warning when you do this.)  To clarify the intent, you can use

```
while((s = vv_pop(vv)) != NULL)
```